# Adding to Values of a Dictionary

Tags: c#

With simpler dictionaries like this `Dictionary<key,value>` I know I can add an item to the dictionary like this:

```
if(!myDic.ContainKeys(key))
  myDic[key] = value;
```

But how about a more complex dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary myDic<string, List<MyClass>>
```

where each key might have a list of values of my class? How do we add to that?

Comment: `myDic.Add("asdf", new List<MyClass>());`. It's no different.

Comment: I'm assuming that the reason for the downvotes is the low difficulty of the question for many developers but I don't like when it happens for that

Comment: @chiapa, (did not vote) downvotes are for lack of research. Image I asked: "I have an apple that I cut with a knife. How do I cut a banana?" We would look at you with confusion for a second and say "...with the same knife...". Same thing here.

Comment: @gunr2171, I understand what you mean but that's not really the case here. Although it may be very simple to you or anyone else to add any object type to a dictionary object, it isn't necessarily to everyone. I know the asker could probably figure it out by himself through researching, tutorials and etc. but it would take him much longer (if he did at all) and, in my opinion, he can learn this way too (in a different way maybe)

Comment: @chiapa, this has been a problem on the site for a while, "simple questions getting downvoted." [Here is a starting link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251513/how-to-deal-with-questions-answerable-with-a-simple-web-search). If you want to discuss this more, please head to [meta].

Comment: @flindeberg this is an already answered question you are commenting on and trying to solve!

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack Indeed, it was more of a comment that the question did not show proper research ;) Just because a question is answered does not necessarily mean it is properly asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that I use for this:

```
// This is the list to which you would ultimately add your value
List<MyClass> theList;
// Check if the list is already there
if (!myDict.TryGetValue(key, out theList)) {
    // No, the list is not there. Create a new list...
    theList = new List<MyCLass>();
    // ...and add it to the dictionary
    myDict.Add(key, theList);
}
// theList is not null regardless of the path we take.
// Add the value to the list.
theList.Add(newValue);
```

This is the most "economical" approach, because it does not perform multiple searches on the dictionary.

Comment: +1, only one nitpick: _"theList is not null regardless of the path we take"_ That's not true if somebody sets the reference to null explicitly. So the dictionary can contain a list for this key which is null.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are right, I did make an assumption that this is the only piece of code that accesses `myDict`.

Comment: whew! Finally I understood it. Very nice. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think you should move the last line(theList.Add part ) inside the brakcets..or it may add some item to the list two times

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack No, the last line is outside the `if` block on purpose. It needs to be executed both in case when `if` succeeds, but also in case that the `if` fails. In the later case the object in `theList` will be set by `TryGetValue`.

Answer (score 5):

The same way:

```
myDic[key] = new List<MyClass()>();
```

If the list is already there and you want to add to it:

```
myDic[key].Add(new MyClass());
```

Comment: oh I didn't know that's how we "add" to it, Ok thanks.

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack, for the record, both `Dictionary` and `List` have `Add` methods. This `Add` if for the List, which adds a single item to the list in your dictionary value. You can also do `Add` for the dictionary.

Comment: So I think I don't even need to check for existence of the key with "ContainsKey" ? If I always use add, because it is a List of values for that key, either it will be a list with one member or with more members...Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack: The `Add` here is adding to the list. `myDic[key]` will return a list and you are adding to that. There is an `Add` for the dictionary too, but that's not what we are doing here. I left out checking `ContainsKey` since you seem to already have that idea. If all you are doing is inserting a new or replacing an old item, then you don't actually need it. If you are looking to add an item to the list contained in the dictionary, then you probably want to check it exists first or you'll get  `KeyNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TryGetValue` method:

```
List<MyClass> list;

if (myDic.TryGetValue(key, out list))
  list.Add(value); // <- Add value into existing list
else
  myDic.Add(key, new List<MyClass>() {value}); // <- Add new list with one value
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value to add is an item for the list, you can do:

```
if(!myDic.Keys.Contains(key)) {
    myDic[key] = new List<MyClass>();
}
myDic[key].Add(value);
```